# Help me fix a loose pedal-arm on a fixie!

Tags: repair, parts, fixed-gear, advice

Basically, after a few months of riding my bike, the pedal arms start to loosen up every few weeks after skidding/backpedaling. I ended up having to pedal with one foot for at least 2kms today (I know, bad idea).
[image]

What is a possible fix for this problem?
I definitely saw metal dust from abrasion. Also may have seen a bit of worn thread on the pedal-arm. Someone told me to replace the self-extracting bolt on the NDS. There’s more to see in the photos I’ve added.
[image]

I greatly appreciate all your contributions, this really helps me out.[image]

Answer (score 3):

> What is a possible fix for this problem?

Loctite.  Blue.

I have an FSA-based SRM power meter where the self-extracting crank bolt simply will not stay properly torqued without using Loctite.  That's probably pretty similar to the problems you're having. And I'm not backpedaling or skidding with that bike...

I bought the SRM crankset used, so maybe it was ridden with a loose bolt and the crankarm/spindle interface was damaged/distorted prior to my purchasing it, similar to what happens with a square-taper crankset.

I replaced the self-extracting bolt, and that didn't help.

But using blue Loctite works for me.

If that doesn't work for you, you might have to replace your crankset.

I don't recommend red Loctite...

Comment: Permatex makes a fancy orange intermediate strength threadlocker that would be nice here.

Comment: Oh what about red loctite? Heard that it is stronger than the blue loctite. Skidding will definitely happen at some point, it is quite inevitable with a fixie. I'm eyeing 262 Loctite Red right now. Finding a single crank arm is a nightmare and outright impossible.

Comment: @Nearfreak Red Loctite?  There's a good chance you'll never be able to get it off.